# Calculate true positive, true negative, false positive and false negative in clustering MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can I get the confusion matrix of a clustering in matlab? 
I used combination of dbscan and linkage clustering methods. From dbscan I taken the corepts,based on that I grouped data again based on distance and applied linkage. Now I need to calculate confusion matrix from that.Core is the corepts of dbscan(core=data(corepts)).Anybody, please help me.

```
[i,id] = mink(abs(data(:)-core(:).'),25);
clusters = data(id);
link=linkage(clusters);
```

Comment: All you need is a list of classification result and expected class for each element classified. Do you have that? It’s not clear from your code excerpt.

Comment: I am doing clustering. Is it possible to find cluster accuracy rate?

Comment: If you don’t have a ground truth, then you don’t know how well the clustering did. There’s no way to define an accuracy or true positive rate etc if you don’t have a ground truth.

Comment: I have clustering output(result) and the number of classes of a data set. Is it possible to get a ground truth from this. The result is in the link variable.

Comment: no. You need to have a list with the correct results (you can use `confusionmat`). Otherwise, you can only do plausability checks.

Comment: How to create confusion matrix with cluster outputs?